# How to find installed Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: 14.04, software-center, oracle, sqldeveloper

I have a strange problem I never had before.

I have Oracle SQL Developer installed. If I run the install .deb file, it shows in my Software Center that it is installed. And this is true because I can run it from the terminal with command `sqldeveloper` .

However, it's not showing up in my software list and I can't search for it like I can for other programs. How can I put it on the list of installed programs? I don't understand why it's not there already...

Any help would be appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

> `which sqldeveloper`

to see where the executable script is installed.

To make it easier to use, you can create a desktop icon. So create a file `sqldeveloper.desktop` anywhere you wish:

```
cd /path/to/your/desktop/
nano sqldeveloper.desktop
```

and populate it with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/path/to/sqldeveloper/script
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;Oracle;
Type=Application
Icon=path/so/some/image
Name=Oracle SQL Developer
```

and update:

> `sudo update-desktop-database`

Comment: I did this as you say. And what do I do then? I now have a file on desktop called `sqldeveloper.desktop`, which doesn't do anything if I try to open it...

Comment: what does `which sqldeveloper` say? Use that path in `Exec=/path/to/sqldeveloper/script`. .

Comment: I also forgot to add `[Desktop Entry]`, apparently important. This works now, thank you very much for the help!